# How to further optimize calculating all the cross sums?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I had some spare time yesterday and somehow thought about calculating cross sums.
My goal is to calculate all the sums up to a given number n. Don't ask why - it's just for fun and to learn stuff.
So for n = 11 I want my result to look something like this: [1, 2, 3, 4,  5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]

This is my code:

```
def dynamicCheckSumList(upperLimit):
    dynamicChecksumList = []
    for i in range(0, 10):
        dynamicChecksumList.append(i)
    for i in range(10, upperLimit+1):
        length = getIntegerPlaces(i)
        size = 10**(length-1)
        firstNumber = i // size
        ancestor = i-(firstNumber*size)
        newChecksum = firstNumber + dynamicChecksumList[ancestor]
        dynamicChecksumList.append(newChecksum)
    return dynamicChecksumList
```

At first I create my empty list and then populate the numbers 0-9 with their respective trivial sums.
Then I look at all numbers above 9 until the upper limit. Get their length. I then continue with finding out the first digit of the number. After that I calculate the number without that leading digit. For example: If my i is 5432 I will get 432. Since I already saved the cross sum for 432 I can just add that cross sum to my leading digit and I'm basically done.

```
def getIntegerPlaces(theNumber):
    if theNumber <= 999999999999997:
        return int(math.log10(theNumber)) + 1
    else:
        counter = 15
        while theNumber >= 10**counter:
            counter += 1
        return counter
```

The second function is something I found here at a question of something asking on how to calculate the number of digits in a given number.

Is there any way in here (I guess there will be) to speed up things?
Also appreciated would be tips on how to save on memory. Just for fun I tried to set n to 1 billion. And my memory (16GB) kind of exploded ;)

Comment: What do you call a cross sum ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def digitSums2(n):
    n = (n + 9) // 10 * 10 # round up to a multiple of 10
    result = bytearray(range(10))
    for decade in range(1, n//10):
        r_decade = result[decade]
        for digit in range(10):
            result.append(r_decade + digit)
    return result
```

There are two primary differences are:

- `bytearray` uses a single byte per calculated value, which saves a lot of memory. It only allows numbers up to 255, but it is sufficient for numbers that have less than 26 digits.
- Peeling of the last digit is much easier then peeling of the first one.

This should be about as fast as possible in python. Be careful with printing results, since it can take more time than calculation itself (especially if you do in-memory copies).